# How to get value of an object using typescript in a generic react hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am creating a simple hook to retrieve option objects by providing the `items`, `labelKey` and `valueKey`.

This is my interface for the hook parameters:

```
interface IProps<T> {
  items: T[];
  labelKey: keyof T;
  valueKey: keyof T;
}
```

And this is the hook itself:

```
const useOptions = <T extends object>(props: IProps<T>) => {
  const { items, labelKey, valueKey } = props;

  const options = useMemo<SelectOption[]>(() => {
    return items.map((item) => ({
      label: item[labelKey],
      value: item[valueKey],
    }));
  }, [items]);
  return options;
};

export default useOptions;
```

And finally this is the `SelectOption` and I am planning to get an array of this type.

```
export interface SelectOption {
  value: number | string;
  label: number | string;
}
```

I am so close but I couldn't find what I'm missing here. This is the typscript error that I see:

```
Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now `T` could have any shape. You only constrained `T` to be an `object` type. But you are trying to assign values inside `T` to the properties of `SelectOption`. Both properties of `SelectOption` only accept `string` or `number` as their values which explains the error.

We could constrain `T` to also only have `number | string` properties.

```
const useOptions = <
  T extends Record<string, string | number>
>(props: IProps<T>) => {
   /* ... */
};
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgLJIgRwC+cAZlBCHAERSobMBQnwAdjEii10SOAEkACgzCEAPABUAfLk5w4wASEIAuOPIDaAXQDcquABsUAIyTmA0kgCeugNZOItPabUA3FOfwkB2c4N0cPL04qbiQAD0hYdX5BYTRRAGVbJAwAeTAYYAheFV9-QN1efBAbKDgAHzhCGCg+AHNvC2tbCqqa+sbmttNozjQipoJiPILxuABeOAU4OIFeABNCRGzoNdkmlt5W7H22-srqwUVFAAowaR1xKQgZBUUASnnlHDMx3gm8DTkQjYSw2exObB+AJBJzUeZwO7PQimH7jeDPGZ-eFEUjkCCyTLmbIwaaFXhGG7XD5zL5mNRsGD4KDFQFaAB0IBQYGu11Z1OU12+amFnTBulZ+lBtmChkwdOFUPK6k0+kVMMcsvlVDebw6VGw+lZhEMurMDKZxVka2APkUONJ41kAHprbbhii4gl4GskMJ8OZ4Pb8mTkUA)

Comment: In that case my Item object will be constrained to have `number | string` for its each property but this won't be the case all the time, it may have nested objects or arrays etc. Am I wrong?

Comment: Could you share some sample data. So that we know how the Array of `T` would Look like and what the resulting `options` Array would be

Comment: Actually `T` can be any valid object. Since this hook will be used throughout the whole application, I cannot predict the shape but yeah, as I said it can be any valid JS object.